# ActiveX common dialog control error in C#

Tags: c#, .net

i have encountered a weird error in a sample code of Arcobjects, but the error seems not to be part of arcobjects

this the part of code where the error occurs :

```
        // Get the typeinfo for the ActiveX common dialog control
        typ = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MSComDlg.CommonDialog");

        // Create an instance of the control.  We pass it to the property frame function
        // so the property pages have an object from which to get current settings and apply
        // new settings.
        obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typ); ///////the error occurs here 
        // This handy function calls IPersistStreamInit->New on COM objects to initialize them
        ActiveXMessageFormatter.InitStreamedObject(obj);
```

when the execution reaches this line  `obj = Activator.CreateInstance(typ);` i get this error `COM EXCEPTION WAS UNHANDELED BY THE USER`

Any help please

Comment: That isn't much to go by but I can guess.  That code uses an ancient VB6 control.  Which got a security patch last April that fixed a nasty remote code execution vulnerability.  That patch changed the CLSID of the control.  Of course, that patch didn't also update ArcGIS.  Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i'm working on XP SP3 with no updates , this info can reveal some solutions ?